# Vaadin close UI of same user in another browser/tab/system

Tags: session, authentication, vaadin7

I'm doing a project in Vaadin 7. In that I need to implement something like below for the login.

A user 'A' is logged in to a system '1'. And again he logs into another system '2'. Now I want to know how to close the UI on the system '1'.

I tried something and can able to close the UI, If it is the same browser. But, for different systems/browser. I don't have any idea.

My Code:

```
private void closeUI(String attribute) {
        for (UI ui : getSession().getUIs()) {
            if(ui.getSession().getAttribute(attribute) != null)
                   if(ui.getSession().getAttribute(attribute).equals(attribute))
                         ui.close();

            }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I also have the same problem. But your code is not working for me.

Comment: Did you set the session attribute. Try this.
getUI().getSession().setAttribute(attribute, attribute);

Comment: Are "system 1" and "system 2" Vaadin apps from the same project running under the same tomcat?

Comment: @Grove Yeah.. Both are same app running under same tomcat..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a situation similar to your where I need to display several info regarding all sessions. What I did was I created my own Servlet extending the VaadinServlet with a static ConcurrentHashmap to save my sessions info, and a SessionDestroyListener to remove any info from the map upon logout. Initially I also had a SessionInitListener where I added the info in the hashmap but I realized I only had the user information after authentication so I moved this part to the page handling the login.

I guess you could do something similar, or at least this should get you started:

```
public class SessionInfoServlet extends VaadinServlet {

  private static final ConcurrentHashMap<User, VaadinSession> userSessionInfo = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  // this could be called after login to save the session info
  public static void saveUserSessionInfo(User user, VaadinSession session) {
    VaadinSession oldSession = userSessionInfo.get(user);
    if(oldSession != null){
      // close the old session
      oldSession.close();
    }
    userSessionInfo.put(user, session);
  }

  public static Map<User, VaadinSession> getUserSessionInfos() {
    // access the cache if we need to, otherwise useless and removable
    return userSessionInfo;
  }

  @Override
  protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
    super.servletInitialized();
    // register our session destroy listener
    SessionLifecycleListener sessionLifecycleListener = new SessionLifecycleListener();
    getService().addSessionDestroyListener(sessionLifecycleListener);
  }

  private class SessionLifecycleListener implements SessionDestroyListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroy(SessionDestroyEvent event) {
      // remove saved session from cache, for the user that was stored in it
      userSessionInfo.remove(event.getSession().getAttribute("user"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Grove. It is really a good hint for me. I will work on it.

Comment: No problem, happy to have helped

Comment: how is this working? I tried this code and opened the app on 2 different browsers with the same login and it opens and 2 session are active, because I think the userSessionInfo get empty everytime

Comment: @user2137817 If `get` always returns null, then `put` is never called. Are you invoking `saveUserSessionInfo` at login time or anywhere in your app?

Comment: I'm calling the saveUserSessionInfo after login. And yes put is called but everytime I run the app on different browser the hashmap is empty again.

Comment: @user2137817 Perhaps your servlet implementation has an instance variable hash map, instead of a class/static one? Some code snippets on pastebin or any other similar service would help a lot.

Comment: I litterally copied your code and put it in my servlet as I use the same things

Comment: @user2137817 In that case only a code snippet may help in isolating the problem.

Comment: I display the hashmap everytime I login in the app and it's null, then add the current user but when I open it again in different browser null again so basically the data is not saved

Comment: @user2137817 Like I said, without seeing the actual code we can not guess what's happening. It is understandable if you do not wish to share your code (might even be copyrighted) but you can either create a simple demo project and upload it somewhere, or use a service like  http://pastebin.com to share only the relevant parts of it.