# Sessions handling in Vaadin

Tags: java, session, authentication, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a `Vaadin` application that starts with a `user login`, but the problem is with `Vaadin` is the session handling as I can open two sessions from 2 different browsers with the same `login` which should not be possible to do. But I did not find any documentation regarding that besides this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594631/vaadin-close-ui-of-same-user-in-another-browser-tab-system) but it's not working properly as the data are not saved in the `hashmap` correctly.Anyone got the same problem?

Comment: " I can open two sessions from 2 different browsers with the same login which should not be possible to do" Is this not typical of most sites? I can log into my hotmail account on one browser & another hotmail account on another for example.

Comment: yeah but this shouldn't happen for security purposes of the app right?

Comment: You should really be able to handle it. Facebook does, twitter does etc.

Comment: yeah but vaadin doesn't :)

Answer (score 4):

Vaadin 7 works by default so that it creates everytime a new UI instance when a new browser tab is opened (or the tab is refreshed). You should store information about current user to `VaadinSession` or standard `HttpSession` and check in `UI.init()` if the session contains user information.

To store information into `VaadinSession` one can say:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("currentUser", currentUser)
```

HttpSession can be accessed as follows in Vaadin:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession()
```

Please note that `VaadinSession`s are stored into `HttpSession` and `HttpSession` can contain multiple `VaadinSession`s if multiple Vaadin servlets are deployed from the same war file, and the user uses those at the same time.

Comment: I tried this using this wiiki https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20login%20view but when I open the app from different browsers it says always user logged in is null

Comment: Do you mean different browsers (eg. Firefox vs. Chrome) or tabs/windows inside the same browser?

Comment: Session is not shared between different browsers. However it's shared between different browser windows or tabs inside the same browser.

Comment: Well that's a big problem! if a lot of users using different browsers and systems how to keep track of who's logged in then? cuz now i can login from 2 different browsers with the same login which is dangerous

Comment: You can use a static HashMap for that like instructed on another answer or store the information to a DB for example.

Comment: I did use the hashmap but it's the same thing it doesn't keep track of the data, it gets empty everytime.

Answer (score 2):

How to prevent concurrent logins?

I keep track of logins using a self-generated login-token.  A random string between 32 and 128 bytes in length that gets stored in a cookie and a backend database, typically under a user's account.

If User (A) shares her login credentials with User (B) a new login-token is generated for the new login and stored in a cookie and updated in the backed database.

If User (A) (who might for example already be logged in) attempts to perform an action while User (B) has just logged-in, User (A)'s session will be destroyed and she'll be redirected to the login screen after a backend test confirmed her login-token isn't a match.

Think of Sessions and Logins as two different things.  Sessions can be generated all day long, but login STATE should be stored in a central store.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all logged users to **static** Set. Static variables are globally shared. On start app, check whether the collection is already login.

Comment: I did as it's mentioned in the link I put in my question but it's not working